# How to create a mysql trigger to update a column

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I want to update a column of new inserted row based on value set in another table.

I have created some thing like this :

```
BEGIN
DECLARE value float;
DECLARE comission float;    
DECLARE c float;

select value=`uc_amount` from inserted;

select comission=`config_value` from fixed_configs WHERE `config_key` = 'deal_comission';

c = value - (value * (comission/100));

update user_credits set `uc_admin_amount`=value;

END
```

But its shows error

here table structure

user_credit:

```
uc_amount   float(10,2) 
uc_admin_amount float(5,2)
uc_created  timestamp
uc_extra    text
```

fixed_configs:

config_key varchar(225)
 config_value varchar(225)

Comment: The question is not clear, provide the proper DDL and example data of what should happen.

Comment: shows error on line DECLARE value float;

Comment: I want to update admin comission in new inserted row . Admin comission percentage is stored in another table . so i just want to update admin_amout column of newly inserted row

Comment: Update the question and provide the table structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need 2 triggers one `before insert` and one `before update`

The before insert will get the `uc_amount` and will calculate the `uc_admin_amount` and `before update` will check if the old `uc_amount` is not same as new `uc_amount` and if so do the calculation.

```
delimiter //

create trigger ins_user_credit before insert on user_credit
for each row
begin
 declare comission float(5,2);
 select config_value into comission from fixed_configs WHERE config_key = 'deal_comission';
 set new.uc_admin_amount = new.uc_amount - (new.uc_amount * (comission/100));
end; //

delimiter ;


delimiter //

create trigger upd_user_credit before update on user_credit
for each row
begin
 declare comission float(5,2);
 if(old.uc_amount <> new.uc_amount)
   select config_value into comission from fixed_configs WHERE config_key = 'deal_comission';
   set new.uc_admin_amount = new.uc_amount - (new.uc_amount * (comission/100));
 end if ;
end; //

delimiter ;
```

Comment: my current amount is "20" and commission is "1.5" above trigger set admin amount to 19.70